# conditionally highlight a field in VF

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am comparing two records side by side, and if a field differs in the 2 records, I want to highlight the field in 1 of the records.

Here's how I'm going about it, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountController">
<style type="text/css">
    .highlight {background-color: red;}
    .label {font-weight:bold;}
</style>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection > 
            <apex:outputField value="{!first.name}"/>
            <span class="{!if(first.name != second.name, 'highlight', '')}">
                <apex:outputField value="{!second.name}"/>
            </span>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>    

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection > 
            <apex:outputField value="{!first.name}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!second.name}" rendered="{!first.name = second.name}"/>
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!first.name <> second.site}">
            <apex:outputtext value="second name"/>
            <span style="color:red; font-weight: bold">            
            <apex:outputfield value="{!second.name}" style="color:red"/>    
            </span>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

If your compare has to be case insensitive use rendered="{!upper(first.name) = upper(second.name)}"/> that way you will maintain consistency in data not worrying about the case.

Answer (score 4):

It's best practice to put all your styling in one place, either at the top of the page or in another file which you put into a static resource, that way when you need to change some styling it's easy to find and manage.

For doing a conditional highlight I'd use a CSS class and the `styleClass` parameter available on most VF tags, however the styleClass attribute doesn't apply for every type of value when working with `<apex:outputField>` as detailed in the documentation:

> styleClass - The style class used to display the output field component, used primarily to designate which CSS styles are applied when using an external CSS stylesheet. This attribute may not work for all values. If your text requires a class name, use a wrapping span tag.

So we need to use a span tag to wrap the output:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .highlight
    {
        background-color: red;
        /* I think outputText users 
    }
</style>

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection > 
            <apex:outputField value="{!first.name}"/>
            <span class="{!if(first.name != second.name, 'highlight', '')}">
                <apex:outputField value="{!second.name}"/>
            </span>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

**Page Block Section Fix**

`<apex:pageBlockSection>` tags break down using this approach as the span gets interpreted as it's own table element in the resulting grid. The only way I've found to tackle this so far is a little messy but it does work:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>
  <apex:outputField value="{!first.name}"/>
  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel value="Account"/>
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="{!IF(first.name != second.name, 'red', '')}">
      <apex:outputText value="{!second.name}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: were you able to test this? I tried the same and I was not able to get the background color on the outputfield

Comment: Good catch @rao! `<apex:outputField>` has some funkiness around the `styleClass` attribute.

Comment: @LaceySnr - it's not working, does this code work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This example from Keir Bowden's book '[Visualforce Development Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/visualforce-development-cookbook)' helps to explain this a lot.

```
<apex:page StandardController="Campaign" recordSetVar="Campaigns">
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Campaigns"/>
  <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Campaigns}" var="campaign">
      <apex:column value="{!campaign.Name}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!campaign.BudgetedCost}"/>
      <apex:column style="color: {!IF(AND(NOT(ISNULL(campaign.ActualCost)), campaign.ActualCost<=campaign.BudgetedCost), "lawngreen", "red")}" value="{!campaign.ActualCost}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```